# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt fails

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

At first I could run the inlezen3.py script fine, and I could plot using the matplotlib library. Than suddenly it can no longer find the matplotlib module, I get an error at the following line of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The error is that it can't find the matplotlib module:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
```

The whole error traceback:

```
(code) PS C:\Users\Me\dev\2020-08-21_Analyse_Sunridge\code> python inlezen3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inlezen3.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Me\dev\2020-08-21_Analyse_Sunridge\code\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\Me\dev\2020-08-21_Analyse_Sunridge\code\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 168, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "C:\Users\Me\dev\2020-08-21_Analyse_Sunridge\code\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
(code) PS C:\Users\Me\dev\2020-08-21_Analyse_Sunridge\code> python inlezen3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inlezen3.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Me\dev\2020-08-21_Analyse_Sunridge\code\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\Me\dev\2020-08-21_Analyse_Sunridge\code\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 168, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "C:\Users\Me\dev\2020-08-21_Analyse_Sunridge\code\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
```

I tried to use a virtual environment, and install all necesarry packages again in this virtual environment. Installing is no problem, but I again get the same can't find module error.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deinstalling python (in Windows app manager) and next install Anaconda.

Answer (score -2):

You can re install it in CMD type pip install matplotlib

[image]